# How to copy a file from Windows to Windows/Linux uisng Python script

Tags: python

I need to copy a file from Windows to Linux and the Windows machine with the same logic. Is it Possible?

Ex:

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst)

# src im giving as "C:\Temp\x.txt"
dst = "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Test"
```

Showing error:

> No such File or Directory : "\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Test"

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure of Windows and Linux are different. It might make sense to copy something to `C:\Program Files` on Windows, but in Linux you're not going to store applications in `/Program Files`. What you can do, however, is store a file relative to one of the following locations.

**The home directory**

```
pathlib.Path.home() or os.path.expanduser("~")
```

**The current working directory**

```
pathlib.Path.cwd() or os.getcwd()
```

**The current Python file**

```
__FILE__
```

**The temp directory**

```
tempfile.gettempdir()
```

Once you have the folder you're going to start from, you can then get cross-platform subfolders like so.

In Python 3.4+, you would use the pathlib module

`pathlib.Path.home() / "path" / "to" / "somewhere"`

And in older versions of Python you would use the os.path module

`os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "path", "to", "somewhere")`